# It doesn't pick up the variable correctly in subprocess.call (python)

Tags: python, bash, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am creating a telegram bot to send the information that I request to the app.

When I run the code below it works fine except for the last part, when it does the `subprocess.call(['robocop', '--robocop', '--cpu', '--server {f}'])` it doesn't seem to put the correct data of the variable "f" because it gives me information of the server where the python code is, but not of the server that I request.

The robocop script is an app that I have created in bash

```
# Check CPU Status
@bot.message_handler(commands=['cpu'])

def command_long_text(m):

    cid = m.chat.id
    f = (m.text[len("/cpu"):])
    bot.send_message(cid, "Collecting CPU information from " + f)
    bot.send_chat_action(cid, 'typing')
    time.sleep(3)
    subprocess.call(['robocop', '--robocop', '--cpu', '--server {f}'])
```

Could you please help me?

If I change the variable to a string it works correctly.

```
subprocess.call(['robocop', '--robocop', '--cpu', '--server', 'appdb'])
```

Thank you!

Comment: use subprocess.call(['robocop', '--robocop', '--cpu', f'--server {f}'])

Comment: `'--server {f}'` is a static string. You want a formatted string: `f'--server {f}'`.

Comment: Nothing so fancy is needed; `--server` and `f` are two separate arguments to be passed to `robocop`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the right version:

```py
cid = m.chat.id
f = (m.text[len("/cpu"):])
bot.send_message(cid, "Collecting CPU information from " + f)
bot.send_chat_action(cid, 'typing')
time.sleep(3)
subprocess.call(['robocop', '--robocop', '--cpu', f'--server {f}'])
```

A formatted string literal or `f-string` is a string literal that is prefixed with 'f' or 'F'. These strings may contain replacement fields, which are expressions delimited by curly braces {}. While other string literals always have a constant value, formatted strings are really expressions evaluated at run time.

See also [PEP 498](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/).

Comment: That passes `--server whatever` as a *single* argument. It should probably be two separate arguments `--server` and `whatever`. The single argument `--server=whatever` should work as well.

Comment: Which is to say, `['robocop', ..., '--server', f]` should suffice, since `f` is already a string.